# Is it possible to create a mouseover event based on boundaries?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, onmouseover

I have a grid overlay where all the corners of each individual box are saved in an array of arrays (i.e. let boxes = [[x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3],[...]];) I am simulating a force being applied over the whole grid and breaking it down into each square (like a homemade FEA). I want to try to have the force of each square display when the mouse hovers over that range. Is this possible? I know how to do it with div in HTML but I'm not sure how to pull ranges from an array and have the program know the mouse is over that range. Right now I have them displaying with mouse clicks:

```
///Shows force at clicked coordinates
function getCursorPosition(canvas, event){
    let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
    let x    = event.clientX - rect.left
    let y    = event.clientY - rect.top
    for(let i = 0; i < plateForces.length; i++){  
        if( plateForces[i][0] < x && x <= plateForces[i][4] && plateForces[i][1] < y && y <= plateForces[i][5] ) {
            // Point is in bounding box 
            context.fillStyle = "black";
            context.font      = "bold 20px Ariel";  
            context.fillText( JSON.stringify(plateForces[i][8].toFixed(1)), x, y);
        }
    }
    console.log(x,y)

}
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) { getCursorPosition(canvas, e) });
```

any help, or suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this. In this example I am using a basic rectangle collision detection algorithm. In order to do this I gave my mouse object a very small width and height. Now I am able to check for collision.

From there I can pass a colliding cell to a function I called `pressure()` and it will color the cells based on a distance that I set. I used Pythagorean theorem from this.

```
Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)
```

or in JS you can also use Math.hypot

```
Math.hypot(dx, dy)
```

That's about all it takes and you can have different colors based on the distance from the mouse position.

I had no clue how you were creating your grid and cells so I just used a loop to create the grid here.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
let cellSize = 25;
let canvasBounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
let grid = [];
const mouse = {
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  width: 0.1,
  height: 0.1,
  clicked: false
};
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  mouse.x = e.x - canvasBounds.left;
  mouse.y = e.y - canvasBounds.top;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawGrid();
});

class Cell {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = cellSize;
    this.height = cellSize;
    this.c = "transparent";
    this.center = { x: this.x + this.width / 2, y: this.y + this.height / 2 };
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "grey";
    ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.c;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
  collision() {
    if (mouse.x && mouse.y && collision(this, mouse)) {
      pressure(this);
    }
  }
}
function createGrid() {
  for (let y = cellSize; y < canvas.height; y += cellSize) {
    for (let x = 0; x < canvas.width; x += cellSize) {
      grid.push(new Cell(x, y));
    }
  }
}
createGrid();

function drawGrid() {
  for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    grid[i].draw();
    grid[i].collision();
  }
}
drawGrid();

function pressure(cell) {
  for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    if (distance(cell, grid[i]) < 60) {
      cell.c = "red";
      grid[i].c = "orange";
    } else if (distance(cell, grid[i]) > 60 && distance(cell, grid[i]) < 130) {
      grid[i].c = "yellow";
    } else {
      grid[i].c = "transparent";
    }
  }
}

function distance(p1, p2) {
  return Math.hypot(p1.center.x - p2.center.x, p1.center.y - p2.center.y);
}

function collision(first, second) {
  if (
    !(
      first.x > second.x + second.width ||
      first.x + first.width < second.x ||
      first.y > second.y + second.height ||
      first.y + first.height < second.y
    )
  ) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks man. I was able to reverse engineer and customize it to do exactly what I needed.